# Bash: Complete Multiple Nested Directories with Tab

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, autocomplete

Current `.bashrc`

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
bind 'TAB:menu-complete'
```

Here's the current behaviour I have:

```
$ cd D<TAB>
Desktop/ Documents/ Downloads/
```

I hit `<TAB>` again and it fills in `Desktop/` (and cycles when I keep pressing TAB which is fine)

What I want to know is how I can tell bash to 'select' `Desktop/` (by pressing `/` or something) and start completing the directories inside `Desktop/` when I next press `<TAB>`?

(I guess as a workaround if there's a way for bash to not append the `/` then I can manually press `/` and then `<TAB>` and it will start completing from there?)

Comment: Welcome, if you press `/` after the completion as in `Desktop//` you get the auto-complete behaviour.

Comment: Oh wow it was that simple, thanks a lot!